# Turning a SpatRaster object to a SpatialGridDataFrame

Tags: r, terra

How to convert a `SpatRaster` object (from the `terra` package) to a `SpatialGridDataFrame` object?

```
r <- terra::rast(matrix(runif(10), 5, 5))
as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
```

> Error in as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame") :
> no method or default for coercing “SpatRaster” to “SpatialGridDataFrame”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through raster:

```
library(terra)
library(raster)

x <- terra::rast(matrix(runif(25), 5, 5))
y <- raster(x)
z <- as(y, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
```

Comment: I actually get the same coercing error when passing the `SpatRaster` object to `raster()`.

Comment: Make sure your packages are up to date